# Assigning a static IP to device to run TCP Server for public IP's

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to make my C++ TCP Server, which I'm running at my house, accessible from the Internet. Server needs to be accessible from public IPs rather than just local IPs (eg. 192.168.20.*).

I've called up my ISP asking about static IPs (with my lack of networking knowledge) and they said I would need to buy a public static IP for a monthly fee?

Do I have other options?
What I'have to do to make my server available from the internet, I'm guessing there is something more to it than just acquiring a public IP?

Comment: Why do you think you can do this without a static IP provided by your ISP?

Comment: I'm new to this networking stuff, I thought this was creating a static ip, but if I have to get a static ip from my isp, then that would answer my question, I was just trying to find a work around.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. There may be work-arrounds like using dynamic DNS.  Your router does, by default have an assigned IP address so that internal devices can reach it - however this address is not exposed to the outside world - a process called NAT maps your internal IP addresses to an external IP provided by your ISP. It is this IP which is normally static for a server, and this is assigned by your ISP.